# Can an Android app tell which store it was installed from at runtime?

Tags: android, google-play, amazon-appstore

I've got an Android app that's going on multiple app stores. It'd be handy at runtime to know which one it came from so I can provide correct text/instructions/update/payment information etc.

Currently I do a separate build for each store with a compile-time encoded constant. Is there a way my app could tell at runtime which store it had come from? Then I could use the same apk for all stores and it'd reduce my maintenance headaches and build times.